# How to run Python installed scripts via py launcher?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Using the [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) works fine: `py.exe -3.5 helloworld.py`

This also works fine to run the corresponding `pip` (which is also not in `PATH`): `py.exe -3.5 -m pip`.

Is there a way to make this also work for installed scripts?

---

Background: This allows installing multiple Python versions in parallel, and using them easily even when they are not in `PATH`. But for example I can't run [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/#).

- `C:\Python35\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe` works.
- `py -3.5 C:\Python35\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py` works, but still requires me to know the installation path.
- `py -3.5 -m pyinstaller` does not work. It just prints `C:\Python35\python.exe: No module named pyinstaller`.
- `py -3.5 -m pyinstaller-script` does not work. It just prints `C:\Python35\python.exe: No module named pyinstaller-script`.

Is there a way to do this anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the module name is incorrect.  This works for me:

```
py -3.5 -m PyInstaller
```

You can see the module names via pip.  For example

```
$ py -m pip list
```

on my workstation shows:

```
Package         Version
--------------- --------
altgraph        0.16.1
cycler          0.10.0
future          0.16.0
kiwisolver      1.0.1
macholib        1.10
matplotlib      2.2.2
numpy           1.15.0
pefile          2018.8.8
pip             10.0.1
PyInstaller     3.3.1
pyparsing       2.2.0
pypiwin32       223
python-dateutil 2.7.3
pytz            2018.5
pywin32         223
setuptools      39.0.1
six             1.11.0
```

Note the case of PyInstaller in the list.